# Is the cross product of two eigenvectors still an eigenvector?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let's suppose I have a symmetric matrix 3x3 and get 2 eigenvalues, one of them with a multiplicity of 2. The eigenvectors of the 2-fold eigenvalue are not immediately perpendicular to each other (They can, but needn't?). Is it correct to assume that if the cross product of the 1-fold eigenvector with one of the vectors of the 2-fold eigenvalue is, first of all, an eigenvector in general and also the second eigenvector for the 2-fold eigenvalue?

Comment: Yes, it holds because a symmetric matrix has orthogonal eigenbasis.

Comment: @Berci True, but a remark for the OP as it's maybe not obvious: an eigenbasis $P$ for a symmetric $A$ is not necessarily orthogonal. Let alone the vector norms, it can happen that $A$ has a multiple eigenvalue, and an eigenspace of dim > 1, and the eigenvectors that are taken as a basis of this eigenspace are not necessarily orthogonal. However, that does not change the answer: the cross product of any two eigenvectors is still an eigenvector.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut that's what I am trying to understand. I know that the eigenvectors to a multiple eigenvalue are not necessarily orthogonal to each other. But if I have an eigenvector from another distinct eigenvalue, the cross product of this one and an eigenvector of my multiple eigenvalue is orthogonal to both of them, and a valid second eigenvector for my multiple eigenvalue. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. If you take the two eigenvectors with a common eigenvalue, the cross product is orthogonal to the eigenspace, thus parallel to the other eigenvector. If you take the third eigenvector and one of the pair, the cross product lies in the vector plane orthogonal to the third eigenvector, si it's in the eigenspace, so it's en eigenvector.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut ok. As an application example: Let A be a symmetric 3x3 matrix with eigenvalue $\lambda_{1} = 1$ and $\lambda_{2,3} = 2$ . The eigenvectors for $\lambda_{2,3}$ aren't orthogonal after calculating them. So its ok if take the eigenvector of $\lambda_{1}$ and one of $\lambda_{2,3}$ calculate the cross product "throw the other original EV of $\lambda_{2,3}$ away" and use the cross product as the new second EV for $\lambda_{2,3}$ ?

Comment: Yes. Or you orthogonalize the basis $(v_2,v_3)$ of the eigenspace, which will yield a similar result.